# How Can I Fix Where The Tile Spawns?

Tags: unity, c#, game-design, game-mechanics, tiles

I am making a 3D game in Unity and C#. I want to spawn another tile when the player is at the end of the current tile. But when I spawn the next tile it doesn't spawn at the right place(just after the current tile). How can I fix this?

Thanks

Old Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Terrain : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> objs = new List<GameObject>();
    public GameObject terrain;
    public GameObject player;
    private float z = 4130.875f;
    private float safeZone = 260.0f;
    private float tileLength = 260.0f;
    private int animTilesCount = 2;
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < animTilesCount; i++)
        {
            spawnTile();
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (player.transform.position.z - safeZone >= (z - objs.Count * tileLength))
        {
            spawnTile();
            DeleteTile();
        }
    }

    public void spawnTile()
    {
        GameObject go;
        go = Instantiate(terrain) as GameObject;
        go.transform.SetParent(transform);
        go.transform.position = Vector3.forward * z;
        Debug.Log(z);
        Debug.Log(Vector3.forward * z);
        Debug.Log(go.transform.position);
        go.transform.rotation = terrain.transform.rotation;
        objs.Add(go);
        z += tileLength;
    }

    public void DeleteTile()
    {
        Destroy(objs[0]);
        objs.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

[image]
[image: Current Tile]
That's the position of the current tile.

The correct position for the next tiles would be (6.103516e-05, 3.051758e-05, z). 
They have to spawn after the current tile.

Comment: Can you show what the inspector shows for the tile's location (as well as what the correct position is)?

Comment: Added the position of the current tile and the correct position of the next tiles.

Comment: Can someone please help me

Comment: Begging is not constructive. If someone hasn't helped you, it's not for lack of sympathy, it's because you haven't given them enough information to know how to help you. So: any time you're tempted to beg, stop, re-read your question, or try reading it to a friend who knows nothing about the problem. Find what might be unclear to a new reader who's never seen your project, and edit it to clarify those points. [Trying to reproduce your problem in a new project given only the information in the question can help you identify what's needed for an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to spawn at an offset from the previous tile, did you try reading the position of the previous tile, and adding onto that?

Just make sure your `objs` list is initialized in the Inspector.

```
public Vector3 nextTileOffset;

public void spawnTile()
{
    Vector3 position = objs[objs.Count - 1].transform.position;
    position += nextTileOffset;

    GameObject go = Instantiate<GameObject>(
                      terrain,
                      position,
                      terrain.transform.rotation );

    go.transform.SetParent(transform);

    objs.Add(go);
}
```

Comment: There is still a gap between the tiles.

Comment: Then add the difference into your `nextTileOffset` variable until they line up.

Comment: I get  this error: ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
Parameter name: index

Comment: Remember when I told you to make sure your objs list is initialized in the Inspector? In order to align with the previous tile, we need there to be at least one tile in the list when we call this function.

Comment: Ok but when I do this : `objs.Add(terrain);` then it instantly deletes terrain after launching the game. I think it's because of  `if (player.transform.position.z - safeZone >= (position.z - objs.Count * tileLength))`

Comment: It sounds like your calculation for when to destroy old/off-screen tiles is incorrect. Try instead `if((objs.Count >1) && (player.transform.position.z - objs[0].transform.position.z  > safeZone))` - ie "If we have more than one tile, and the distance from the first tile to the player is greater than our save zone threshold..." For that to work you'll need to initialize the array with at least two tiles in it. Or separate your spawning & despawning rules rather than putting them in the same `if`.

Comment: Then you need to make sure the two you added manually are in your `objs` array in the right order (first tile first, second tile second), and that your `nextTileOffset` vector and `safeZone` parameters are tuned correctly for the sizes of your tiles.

Comment: Thanks fixed it but when the player is at the end of the first tile, it deletes that tile and spawns another(just like it should) but when the player is at the end of the second tile it doesn't spawn another tile and doesn't delete the second tile.

Comment: Then you've done something wrong beyond the scope of your original question. I'd recommend setting a breakpoint or debug log to investigate why it's not tripping the spawn condition, and ask a new question including that diagnostic information if you can't figure out how to solve it.